# Alphabetical order of strings in a TextFile

Tags: arrays, delphi, sorting, alphabet

I got this list of names in a textfile in a randomn order....how do I sort it in an alphabetical order (delphi) ? I need to keep it in the same text file.
File looks like this:

```
Smith
Jack
Klein
Elliot
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: yes....but i am a real beginner

Answer (score 0):

I would use a TStringlist since it have a buildin function for sorting. Something like this:

```
var
  Stringlist : TStringlist;
begin
  Stringlist := TStringlist.Create;
  StringList.Loadfromfile(MYFILE);
  StringList.sort;
  StringList.saveToFile(MYFILLE);
  StringList.Free;
end;
```

Comment: maybe its because I am using a console

Comment: Add classes to the uses clause

Answer (score -1):

If every word occupies separate line, the simplest way is to use StringList class (I save result in another file for safer debug)

```
with TStringList.Create do try
  LoadFromfile('text.txt');
  Sort; 
  SaveToFile('sortedtext.txt');
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Comment: maybe its because I am using a console

Comment: To use TstringList, add `Classes` in `uses` statement

Comment: Don't afraid evil keywords - learn to cook them properly ;) This is the best application of `with` - very short self-contained task without explicit (redundant) object variable.